# Does anyone know of a good load-on-demand combobox for WPF?

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have been searching for a while now, and have not been able to find a load-on-demand combo box that populates itself depending on what is typed in the combo-box.
I also have a requirement that an item in the list must be selected (i.e.: free text can be entered but not "selected" - only a "search result" can be selected from the list in the combo box.

The scenario is as follows : there is a text box/combo box where someone enter the first 2 or 3 characters, a web service is called which queries a database and then populates the combo box.

Are there any controls or code example that anyone knows of? Or alternatively another way to implement this?

Here is a link to an asp.net control that has this functionality:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/populatingwithdata/autocompletesql/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 1):

use the event "textchanged" to dynamicly add/remove items :)

updated :

why not bind the results to observable collection and databind that to the combo box , so on chnage > query database > bind items to the collection , .net automatilcy updates the items , this might work :)

Comment: Tried that, but when you select an item on the list, the text changes, confuses the hell out of the combobox.
I might have to implement a custom control...

Comment: I have tried binding it to an observable collection, but as I said before the text changes and that rebinds the text and refreshes the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik combobox with autocomplete will be what you are looking for.

Comment: The Telerik combobox has support for autocomplete, not for load on demand. the auto complete only works for items already bound to the combobox.